# How to Search in a PDF File that is loaded from Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, search, highlight

I am making an android application where Users can upload pdf files. I am storing all of these files in firebase storage and then storing there links in firebase Realtime database.
I am using [Barteksc](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) API for loading my pdf file from firebase database. I have successfully loaded and displayed the pdf file.

Now I want to **add a search bar on top of screen so that, when user types any word, It would be searched and highlighted in the pdf file that is being displayed.** The Barteksc API mentioned above do not offers the search functionality. Anyone Knows any other API or any solution to perform search on the PDF that is loaded.

Comment: Does it matter that the file comes from Firebase or could your uncle have sent it too?

Comment: It looks more that you could have asked: `How to Search in a PDF File that is loaded in Barteks Pdf viewer?`. And yet better: `How to Search in a PDF File?`

Comment: @blackapps I have given this title because if someone knows any API or any way by which we could load pdf file from firebase storage and can search in it he can answer it.  **Regardless of Brateks API.** I can change the API if someone could suggest any better solution for loading and performing  search operation in firebase pdf files.

Comment: Does it matter that the file comes from Firebase or could your uncle have sent it too?

Comment: @blackapps and of course YES. It matters that the file should come from firebase database.

Comment: Why? Can you explain? I dont see any reason and you did not tell one either.

Comment: I am working on an Android applications in which I am using firebase database to store pdf files. That's why .

Comment: @blackapps do you know the answer for How to search in pdf files?  If YES then post it. It might be helpful for me.

Comment: If the only thing you want is how to search in pdf files (which i think you want) then please write a post that only askes for that. Dont talk about Firebase or Barteks then.

Comment: @blackapps Are you sure that your answer will be able to search in any pdf file? If Yes then I would change.

Comment: If you're loading the PDF from Firebase through a download URL, then you'd have the same problem when loading from any other URL and it's not specific to Firebase. So in that case, I'd recommend searching for: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+search+in+pdf+files+in+Android+code+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Can you recommend any way for loading a file from firebase. I have saved the file in Firebase storage and link of that file is in Firebase Realtime database.

Comment: That's a very different question, but here too: if you have the download URL, it is no different than downloading from an other URL, so this would be a good starting point: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+download+a+pdf+file+in+Android+code+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: Guys please read my question thoroughly.